# Rigging Problems with vertex groups

Tags: modeling, rigging, eevee-render-engine, normals, vertex-groups

I initially rigged my character with the standard rigify rig provided with the software. I changed my mind afterwards since the face rig they provided didn't work as well for my character art style.[image] Maybe I'm stupid for this, but I tried to simply delete the face bones of the original rig. I then inserted my custom anime face rig into the model and joined it to the rigify rig. This has worked in the past, so I'm a bit surprised here. It wouldn't respond to the new bones, so my smooth brain decided the best way to handle this was to delete all of the vertex groups (safe for a few normal edit groups) and try to start over that way. I thought would make it so that there's no overlap between old vertex groups for the face, and potential new ones. Now it's just comepletly ignoring the rig. It will say that it's created new vertex groups, but none are there.[image] I've tried removing doubles that didn't help. Reseting my normals so that they're all consistent. That didn't work either. Pretty confused....Oddly enough the rig responds to envelope weights so that's just weird. Any help is appreciated. When opening the file, you can press alt H to reveal the original meta rig if that helps. Thank you.

File Download:https://www.mediafire.com/file/m2iiqzby592y29c/Stack_Exchange_Submission.blend/file

Let me know if you have problems with the link :)